# Не могу создать расширяемый массив

Tags: c, указатели

Я только начал изучать C и пытаюсь понять логику указателей. Попытался создать некое подобие расширяемого массива. По логике я хотел сделать так, что каждый раз, когда последний массив-сегмент переполняется значениями, я инициализирую новый с размером в два раза больше всех предыдущих сегментов, вместе взятых.

Я решил реализовать его, используя массив указателей фиксированного размера, который ниже называется `list`, и при "расширении" вместимости инициализирую массив `new_seg` , после чего добавляю его ссылку на его нулевой элемент в `list`.

Для проверки того, что всё работает, я создал метод, который "создает" `list` и  сразу же добавляет четыре сегмента, заполняя значениями, а также метод, который должен проходиться по каждому элементу массива.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int *list[128];
const int default_capacity = 16;
int total_seg_count;
int last_seg_count;
int total_count;
void create_list()
{

    total_seg_count = 0;
    last_seg_count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        increase_capacity();
}
void increase_capacity()
{
    int seg_size = default_capacity * (int)pow(2, (total_seg_count-1)*(0<(total_seg_count-1)));
    printf("new_segment size of %d\n", seg_size);
    int new_seg[seg_size];
    for(int i = 0;i<seg_size;i++)
        *(new_seg+i)=i;
    list[++total_seg_count]=&new_seg;
}
int get_count()
{
    return total_count;
}
int calculate_capacity()
{
    int cap=0;
    for(int i=0;i<total_seg_count;i++)
    {
        printf("size of segment %d: %d\n", i+1, sizeof(*(list[i])));
        cap+=sizeof(*(list[i]))/sizeof(int);
    }
    return cap;
}
void foreach_check()
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<total_seg_count-1;i++)
    {
        int seg_size = default_capacity * pow(2, (i-1)*((i-1)>0));
        printf("segment number %d, sizeof(%d):\n", i+1, seg_size);
        printf("list? %d\n", list[i]);
        for(int j=0;j<seg_size;i++)
        {
            printf("element number %d equals %d\n", counter++, (void*)(*list[i]+j));
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
int get_capacity()
{
    return default_capacity * ((int)pow(2, (total_seg_count-1)*(0<(total_seg_count-1))));
}
int main()
{
    create_list();
    foreach_check();
    return 0;
}
```

Но при попытке перечисления он выходит с ненулевым кодом или где-то зацикливается. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Если после вызова методов из памяти очищаются все значения элементов, кроме тех, которые указаны в `list`, то:
а) Есть ли способ избежать очищения значений, на которые не ссылается `list` без добавления на них указателей?
б) Если пункт а) полный бред и такое невозможно, то как можно реализовать такой расширяемый массив, как описан в первом абзаце?

Был бы очень признателен, если бы мне объяснили, в чем именно я был не прав, выбирая такой подход.

Comment: локальная переменная `int new_seg[seg_size];` теряет своё время жизни при выходе из функции `increase_capacity`. А вы её адрес записываете в `list`. В итоге у вас он будет заполнен бессмысленными *одинаковыми* адресами. Выделять новую память для массивов надо с помощью функции `malloc`.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Есть ли возможность не уничтожать переменную без объявления её глобальной? Как мне исправить этот код таким образом, чтобы данные не уничтожались по завершению метода?

Comment: @AlexGlebe Хорошо, спасибо, попробую

Comment: [man realloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)